# Scheduling command/script by specifying the exact second

Tags: command-line, shell, bash, scripting

I'm using bash and wondering how I can execute a command/script at a later specified time, with the accuracy of a second?

I read the man page for the `at`-command, but as far as I could understand it's only possible specify minutes (and not seconds). Right now I first use `at` and then `sleep` to get it to execute the right second. To demonstrate, if I would like to run my_script.sh at 22.21.05 I would do:

```
echo "sleep 5; my_script.sh" | at 22.21
```

But it would be much nicer to have a command with it built in. Something like `at 22.21.05`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible.  `cron` is only granular down to the minute and the `at` utility hooks into it to do it's work.  I think you have the right solution--sleeping for *x* seconds before executing.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your technique into a function:

```
atplus () { local sec=${1##*.} time=${1%.*}; shift; echo "sleep $sec; $@" | at $time; }
```

Try it out:

```
atplus 22.21.05 my_script.sh
```

You should be aware, however, that precision is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Actually `at` may support seconds

I think this is not always well supported (depending on the particular implementation), but in principle `at` *may* support seconds.

From the man page:

```
-t time run the job at time, given in the format [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]
```

Look at the `[.ss]` at the end.

This means that, using the `-t` option, you can type something like

```
echo "yourscript.sh" | sudo at -t 04281549.45
```

i.e. the command should be executed at `15:49:45` (45 seconds).
(on April the 28th)

When I tried it, as expected the output from `at` was:

```
job 38 at Wed Apr 28 15:49:45 2021
```

**Note**: when I tried it, it was still late by some seconds, but it still was executed *not before* `15:49:45`, meaning that the specified seconds are *not* ignored by `at` internally, they are actually considered. Therefore, specifying seconds can still be useful when you want to say something like "delay this command to run it not earlier than `15:49:45`".

Comment: what version of at? I am running 3.1.23 on two different boxes and neither works the way you show even though the man page shows it just like yours.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not work? What is the output of the command? Do seconds appear in that output?

Comment: I use your exact command and get no second precision.

```job 18 at Wed Apr 28 15:49:00 2021```

Comment: I have just tried with `at` in MacOS Sierra and it has second precision. I cannot tell which version it is, apparently writing `-v` or `--version` does not work...

Comment: ```at -V```. I am 3.1.23 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `-V` (with uppercase V) does not work either. Even `-h` is not supported, and the only way to get an explanation of the possible options is to generate an error (by not giving any argument or by giving incorrect arguments), and even in that case the version is not shown. At this point, I guess it is some "built-in" MacOS version of `at` which is not maintained in a very standard way.